# I'm wondering why after running the SQL query I get this error 1241 - what's wrong here?

Tags: sql, database, business-intelligence

```
CREATE TABLE MOROCCO
( 
    NUM_PER_MANAGE INT , 
    MOYEN_RENT DECIMAL (5,2), 
    GENDER enum ('m','f'), 
    race varchar (205)
);

INSERT INTO morocco (NUM_PER_MANAGE, MOYEN_RENT, GENDER, race) 
VALUES (3, (300, 45), 'm', 'black');
```

Comment: What is the locale of your database?  Do you enter your decimal as `300,45`?  Also, what is your exact database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: What is the excact error message?

Answer (score 0):

you must specify decimal value as **300.45** not (300, 45):

```
INSERT INTO MOROCCO (NUM_PER_MANAGE, MOYEN_RENT, GENDER, race) 
VALUES (3, 300.45, 'm', 'black');
```

and if you are using mysql in linux then you should use the table name in correct case(table name is case sensitive in linux).